# P5 mouse click opens a link

Tags: hyperlink, p5.js

How do I program moving to a new page after a mouse click without a hyperlink?  I want to just draw a circle and if you click in the circle it takes you somewhere.  I am working with P5.js

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`your_circle.mouseClicked(window.open('http://your-link.com'))`

**Reference**:

1. [`mouseClicked()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/mouseClicked)
2. [`window.open()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense.

[You have to split your problem up into smaller pieces.](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) Then take on each of those smaller steps one at a time.

For example, step one might be creating a program that draws a circle. Now detect when the mouse clicks inside that circle. Don't worry about the link yet. Just print something to the console whenever the user clicks the circle.

Step two might be creating a program that opens a link when the user clicks anywhere in the sketch. Don't worry about the circle yet. Googling "JavaScript navigate to new page" or something like that would yield a ton of results.

When you get each of them working perfectly, then you can think about combining them into a single program. And if you get stuck on a specific step, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific question, and we'll go from there. Good luck.